# How the send multiple checkbox values to database in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

This is my view for the customer register.

```
<form action="store" method="post">

    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{csrf_token()}}">

    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <br>

    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="text" name="email">
    <br>

    <label for="country">Country</label>
    <select name="country" id="country">
        <option value="india">India</option>
        <option value="srilanka">SriLanka</option>
        <option value="usa">USA</option>
    </select>
    <br>

    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male">
    <label for="male">Male</label>

    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female">
    <label for="female">Female</label>
    <br>

    <input type="checkbox" name="favorite[]" id="south" value="south">
    <label for="south">South</label>

    <input type="checkbox" name="favorite[]" id="north" value="north">
    <label for="north">North</label>

    <input type="checkbox" name="favorite[]" id="east" value="east">
    <label for="east">East</label>

    <br>

    <label for=""></label>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
```

Well all values are going to database but the checkbox are going as array.

But if i remove [] in favorite. The last checkbox value is going to database.

This is my controller code

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $user= laravel::create(Request::all());
    return "data saved";
}
```

And this is my model

```
class laravel extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 
        "email", 
        "gender", 
        "country", 
        "favorite"
    ];
}
```

Can any one tell me how to send all checkbox values to database whatever customer is checked.

I want to know how to edit checkbox to update.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What type of field is favourite in your database? What does the schema look like? And do you intend to store multiple favorites?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make a text column in your table with the name of `favorite` and use this logic to store your values inside of it as csv

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->merge([ 
        'favorite' => implode(',', (array) $request->get('favorite'))
    ]);

    laravel::create($request->all());

    return "data saved";
}
```

Comment: Nice. Like the use of `->replace`

Comment: @zayn Ali. I updated my code with your code it is showing me. Call to undefined method Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::replace()

Comment: use the `$request` variable which is passed in your controller method. like in used in my answer

Comment: @Zayn Ali. I am geting same error will please check my name space            namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\request;


use App\Http\Requests;

use App\laravel;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;

Comment: public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->replace([ 
        'favorite' => implode(',', (array) $request->get('favorite'))
    ]);

    $user = laravel::create($request->all());

    return "data saved";
    }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120388/discussion-between-zayn-ali-and-jvk).

Comment: @Zayn Ali. Are you there i Have some with laravel

Comment: @ZaynAli Are you there?

Comment: it works for me to insert multiple checkbox values to database: $comp_ids = implode(' ,',(array)$request->get('comp_ids'));